# Plantcv can't build wheel for matplotlib (miniconda3 - python - windows 10)

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I'm trying to install the `PlantCV` package using `pip install plantcv` in `conda`, python-3.11, windows 10. PlantCV requires a lot of dependencies to be installed, so it will try to install them as normal. However, eventually it will output an error message, see below.

Error msg:

```
      error: command 'msbuild' failed: None
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for matplotlib
  Running setup.py clean for matplotlib
Failed to build matplotlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for matplotlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

So it cannot build a wheel for the dependency `matplotlib`. I have tried everything that I could find so far online, but the error message keeps being the same. Strange thing (to me) is, I've installed matplotlib (`pip install matplotlib`) successfully already... I'm at a loss. Could someone please help me?

I've tried:

- update all the dependencies and install the latest versions manually
- update and install the latest version of python and miniconda3
- download and update all Microsoft Visual C++ modules
- Downgrade python and the dependencies to try it this way
- try to install all packages manually, which worked successfully, except plantcv

Comment: If you're using conda, you should be installing all of your libraries using `conda install library_name` rather than pip. So, you can try `conda install plantcv` or `conda install -c bioconda plantcv` (found by searching "plantcv anaconda" on Google and going to the anaconda site).